# How to union two 2D arrays

Tags: java, kotlin

Is there a built in function in the Kotlin or Java standard library to "union" two 2D arrays? By union, I mean the following:

```
val a = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(1, 0),
    arrayOf(0, 0)
)

val b = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(1, 0),
    arrayOf(0, 1)
)

val result = a.union(b) { da, db -> da + db // Decide how to merge the values }
val shouldBe = arrayOf(
    arrayOf(2, 0),
    arrayOf(0, 1)
)

assert(result == shouldBe)
```

The shape of the resulting array should be that of the array which union is called on.

I can obviously write this myself, but wondering if it already exists?

Comment: sounds like you are trying to sum two matrix of 2x2. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Kind of, except it's kind of like a "map" too, because I want to be able to choose how the resulting array is populated based on the values in the source arrays. In my example I am summing yes, but I might want to do something else, like take the minimum, or multiply, or convert to true if they are equal or false if they are not, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, there is nothing built-in. For Kotlin you could have a look at this library by JetBrains: [viktor](https://github.com/JetBrains-Research/viktor). I've not used it, just toyed around with it when the first version was published (so I can't really say anything about it).

If you have only simple cases with 2D-Int-matrices, then you could try something along this:

```
fun Array<Array<Int>>.matrixSum(b: Array<Array<Int>>): Array<Array<Int>> {
  return mapIndexed { indexA, valueA ->
    valueA.mapIndexed { indexB, valueB ->
      valueB + b[indexA][indexB]
    }.toTypedArray()
  }.toTypedArray()
}

val a = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 0), arrayOf(0, 0))
val b = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 0), arrayOf(0, 1))

val result = a.matrixSum(b)
```

Or you hand over the operation to apply as argument:

```
fun Array<Array<Int>>.matrixOp(b: Array<Array<Int>>, op: (Int, Int) -> Int): Array<Array<Int>> {
  return mapIndexed { indexA, valueA ->
    valueA.mapIndexed { indexB, valueB ->
      op(valueB, b[indexA][indexB])
    }.toTypedArray()
  }.toTypedArray()
}

val a = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 0), arrayOf(0, 0))
val b = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 0), arrayOf(0, 1))

val summed = a.matrixOp(b) { i1, i2 -> i1 + i2 }
val multiplied = a.matrixOp(b) { i1, i2 -> i1 * i2 }
```